# R: Forgetting Defined Variable formula definition

Tags: r, variables, definition

How do we rediscover how previously defined variables were defined?

**Example:**

```
a<-5
b<-10
c<-a+b #find C
```

If we type c or print(c) we would get 15 but how do we get a + b instead?

how do we do this generally to find the definition of previously defined variables?

Comment: Your question is unclear. There are mechanisms within R that will store an unevaluated expression, which can be evaluated at a later time. But what's your goal here?

Comment: Sorry for the sloppyness here -- not working on a particular project but just trying to gain a better mastery in R. From time to time, I would forget the definition of a variable and would like to know how it was defined. In the example above, how can I see c as a+b instead of the numeric value 15? or maybe this is not possible?  Another example is fx<-function(x){exp(x)+exp(x)^2}  then if i write "fx" on the console it would spit function(x){exp(x)+exp(x)^2} and thats clear and what im looking for in the same manner in the a, b, c example above.

Comment: Variables have no memory of how they got their value. R can keep track of relationships between variables in different data types like an un-evaualted expression `quote(a+b)` or formula `~a+b` but once it's been evaluated, you can't get back to where it came from. If you really want to track relationships, you'd be better off writing functions in R with clear input and output.

Comment: oh ok thats what im looking for. thank you!